# Intuition on differentiable stacks

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, orbifolds

I'm currently writing my master thesis on "Differentiable Stacks". I'm really fascinated by the idea of generalizing manifolds to include also orbifolds/leaf spaces of foliations/moduli spaces...

I formally understand the construction of differentiable stacks as stacks on the category of smooth manifolds possessing a representable epimorphism. And I formally understand why they generalize smooth manifolds.

What I'm having some trouble to get is: how does one come up with such a definition?

I really read many sources on the topic and none of them justifies the choice of such a definition for differentiable stacks (I mean the existence of a representable epimorphism aka an atlas).

This "intuition problem" is getting better as I familiarize more with this object but I feel like I'm just "getting used to it". I'd like to know how this object was born and what's the idea behind it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm really looking for an approach/intuition from the viewpoint of differential geometry.

Comment: The objects were born in the algebraic category, not in the smooth category, were they not?

Comment: @TedShifrin Does this automatically imply that there is no differential-geometric motivation or intuition for the introduction of such concept in differential geometry?

Comment: I may add an answer later if I remember, but Behrend's notes might be of interest (if you haven't seen them already). https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/math615A/stacksintro.pdf